# has_one select from many basing on parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an polymorphic model called Address. What I'm trying to achieve is to havy **many** addresses binded to other models (for example User), but still use them like if there was **only one**, and try to distinguish them by type.

My project was designed to use only one address, so i have a lot pieces of code like `User.first.address` or `User.first.address=...` which i can do nothing about.

Here is sort of example:

```
|id|addressable_type|addressable_id| type   | street |
  1|User            |1             | first  | Foo
  2|User            |1             | second | Bar  
  3|User            |1             | NULL   | Other
```

And what i want to do is:

```
User.find(1).address(:second)
```

Which should return `<Address street:"Bar">`,

```
User.find(1).address
```

Which should return `<Address street:"Other">`, 
but `User.find(1).addresses` should return collection of objects.

I work with a piece of code to add address behaviour to my models:

```
    module Ext::Models::Addressable

def self.included(mod)
    super
    mod.class_eval do
      def self.acts_as_addressable          
        include InstanceMethods

        # Use has_many :delete_all for better performance
        has_many :addresses, :as => :addressable, :dependent => :delete_all
        has_one :address, :as => :addressable
      end
    end
end

module InstanceMethods
            # I tried with this, but this doesn't even allow me to start rails becauses raises "there is no address method"  
    def address_with_type(type = nil)
        if type
            self.addresses.find(:first, :conditions => ["type = ?", type.to_s])
        else
            address_without_type
        end
    end
    alias_method_chain :address, :type
end
end
```

I'm using Rails 2.3.14 and Ruby 1.9.2.

If this is possible i also'd like to know what is best way to create new addresses for given model (lets say User).

Thanks in advance.

## Solution

I narrowed down all the possibilites, and currently in project there are only two types of addresses. I was able to simplify my approach a lot. Currently my `self.included` looks like:

```
has_many :addresses, :as => :addressable, :dependent => :delete_all
has_one :address, :as => :addressable, :conditions => {:type => nil}
has_one :foo_address, :class_name => 'Address', :as => :addressable, :conditions => {:type => "foo"}
```

And now i'm able to build new object like this:
`user.build_address(:street => "abc")` and `user.build_foo_address(:street => "def")`, what is exacly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I would be a bit careful about overriding default and expected behaviour in that way. Is there a reason you cant let `user.address` be?

I'm not exactly sure what problems you are solving but maybe you could do something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses, :as => :addressable, :dependent => :delete_all

  def address(only_type = "primary")
    addresses.find_first("type" => only_type)
  end

  def address=(addr)
    addresses.delete address
    addresses << addr.update_attribute("type", "primary")
  end

  def build_address(attr)
    addresses.delete address
    addresses.build attr.merge("type" => "primary")
  end

  def create_address(attr)
    addresses.delete address
    addresses.create attr.merge("type" => "primary")
  end
end
```

I haven't tested this code and I'm not that familiar with rails 2 any more so just use it as inspiration. You could wrap it in some meta stuff to modularize it. Btw, if you are using "type" you get STI, not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I managed to fix the problem by different approach. I updated my question with new code.